# Differences of require vs requirejs calls

Tags: requirejs

I'm new to Require.js and I saw the API doc use `require` and `requirejs`. Are they the same or different? How different?

requirejs usage:

```
requirejs.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
    //load it from the js/app directory. paths
    //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    //never includes a ".js" extension since
    //the paths config could be for a directory.
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});
```

require usage:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        foo: 'libs/foo-1.1.3'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load RequireJS, it exports in the global space the symbols `requirejs` and `require` which are the same object.

When you are *inside* a module, `require` and `requirejs` are not necessarily the same object. Consider this test:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    console.log(require === requirejs);
});
```

The value output to the console will *generally* be false. (As I recall from reading RequireJS' code, it will *always* be false but I may be misremembering.)

Comment: That is interesting. I wonder how does it compare two functions for equality.

Comment: For two functions to be equal, they have to be the same ``Function`` object. For instance, if you have the code `var foo = function () {}; var blah = function () {}; foo === blah`, the result is `false`, although the too functions appear to be the same.